# python fabric execute error

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I execute fabric with both fab.exe and run python script directly.

But it shows error.

My PC is Windows 7, Python 2.7.13

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\fabric_test.py", line 3, in <module>
        from fabric.api import run,env,execute,task
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\api.py", line 10, in <module>
        from fabric.context_managers import (cd, hide, settings, show, path, prefix,
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\context_managers.py", line 41, in <module>
        from fabric.state import output, win32, connections, env
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\state.py", line 9, in <module>
        from fabric.network import HostConnectionCache, ssh
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\network.py", line 24, in <module>
        import paramiko as ssh
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
        from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 56, in <module>
        from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\dsskey.py", line 27, in <module>
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.utils import (
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\asymmetric\utils.py", line 9, in <module>
        from asn1crypto.algos import DSASignature
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\algos.py", line 23, in <module>
        from ._int import fill_width
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_int.py", line 56, in <module>
        from ._perf._big_num_ctypes import libcrypto
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\_perf\_big_num_ctypes.py", line 31, in <module>
        libcrypto_path = find_library('crypto')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\util.py", line 53, in find_library
        fname = os.path.join(directory, name)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
        result_path = result_path + p_path
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

what's the problem?

Comment: Are you able to change the text codec from `ascii` to `utf8`?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans I don't know how to change the text codec. But I think the cause is not on the my source file. I got the same error when just running 'fab.exe'.

Comment: Please post your `C:\fabric_test.py`

Answer (score 0):

I hack the C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py file.
add this source code to header of that file. (17 line)

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('euc-kr')
```

then, error disappear. fabric works fine.

but i don't know reason.
what's the problem in my pc?

I want solve this problem without hack.